# Load multiple application stylesheets in asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have several company theme specific stylesheets in my application and a specific stylesheet is loaded based on the logged in user. This is done by loading a specific version of the application file like this in 'application.html.erb':

```
<% if current_user %>
    <% stylesheet_link_tag "application_" + current_user.company.code.downcase %>   
<% else %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<% end %>
```

Ths works fine locally, but on production (after a 'rake assets:precompile'), it doesn't work because it seems only the original 'application.css.scss' gets compiled, not the other ones like e.g. 'application_sal.css.scss'. What am I doing wrong here?

And is this the way to go? When a user is logged in the specific application file is loaded, which contains the company specific stylesheet:

```
@import "_variables.css.scss";
@import "_mixins.css.scss";
@import "_reset.css.scss";
@import "_layout.css.scss";
@import "_skeleton.css.scss";

@import "_theme_sal.css.scss";

@import "_form.css.scss";
@import "base.css.scss";
@import "print.css.scss";
@import "_modules.css.scss";
```

When a user is not logged in, the default application file gets loaded:

```
@import "_variables.css.scss";
@import "_mixins.css.scss";
@import "_reset.css.scss";
@import "_layout.css.scss";
@import "_skeleton.css.scss";
@import "_form.css.scss";
@import "base.css.scss";
@import "print.css.scss";
@import "_modules.css.scss";
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the precompile config item in `environments/production.rb`. While `application.css` is auto precompiled, others will not be without this config item.

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
config.assets.precompile += %w( search.css )
```

Just place each of the company specific css manifest files in the array.

This config item may already be in your `production.rb` commented out, depending on what version of Rails you ran `rails new` under.

Comment: To be clear, .scss extensions can be ignored when you add file names in config.assets.precompile. so if your filename is search.css.scss just add 'search.css' as above.